# My desktop is gone and no access to Konsole, what should I do?

Tags: kubuntu

My desktop just disappeared and all menus with it :
    ctrl + alt + T doesn't work
    ctrl + alt + F1 ask me login ids I don't know (I tried everything.. and I checked if password were the one I wanted by typing it in the login section).
I'm using latest Kubuntu and I have an only environment desktop

Quite desperate...

Comment: What did you do *before* this happend?

Comment: Nothing.. was on Firefox and it just disappeared but the Firefox window is still here even if I reboot